# Can my isp see my sock5 proxy traffic?

Tags: privacy, proxy, proxychains, socks5

I browse the internet/ connect via rdp computers via a sock5 proxy.  I use proxifier to do this and I set it so that it handles dns requests via the proxy.  I am sure there are no dns leaks.  Can my ISP still see/monitor my web traffic?

Answer (score 4):

**YES**

SOCKS5 is a **proxy**, which means the traffic will go directly to it before the target. There is no encryption, so everything is plain text.

Taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/

> SOCKS5 is just a transport protocol on top of TCP/UDP but below application layer. Thus it's comparable with TCP and UDP, too. There's no inherent encryption in SOCKS, but you application has to care about this (it's not a VPN technology, but a proxy at last). If you want encryption, the protocol you speak inside of the SOCKS-channel has to provide it.

[SOCKS5 is there encryption between client and proxy server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123419/socks5-is-there-encryption-between-client-and-proxy-server)

Answer (score 2):

SOCKS5 is a traffic encapsulation protocol which contains no kind of encryption or integrity protection. Anybody able to sniff the connection can see what you are doing and an active attacker (i.e. usually in the path) could even modify the traffic so that you would not notice. This means that your ISP is able to monitor and filter your traffic if he wants to.